# Searching full content with Si4T

Tags: dd4t, search, si4t, solr

We noticed that searching with DD4T 1.1, Si4T the body content (of RTF and binaries) was not being searched.

We have the required  setting but this doesn't change anything so we tried and found that adding

df=body

to the querystring does return search results including the body - however, this then negates the 'suppress from search' and the _000 Index pages are showing.

Is there a way without core development to allow full-text search (not just the headline as it appears out of the box) and still use the existing *suppress from search* filter; I was hoping there is a simply 'querystring hack' where I can indicate :

*search term IN full body excluding 'starts with _000' and excluding 'suppress from search' and excluding '*.pdf'*

I'm still trawling through SOLR documentation and would appreciate any direction!

Comment: Sounds like you only want to search in certain publications? Is that assumption correct?

Comment: I've done more testing and the publication filter is still being 'adhered' to (as required - out of the box for the DXA implementation) so the addition of df=body to the URL isn't affecting the index publication filtering. The requirement is more to include searching through body content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean DXA 1.1 or DD4T 1.1? In either case, if the body field is not being searched, it sounds like your SOLR configuration is not correct. The body field should be the [default search field](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Default_Search_Field) I guess...

I am not sure what the *suppress from search* thing you are talking about is? In DXA/SI4T there is a metadata field to prevent the page being indexed - but in this case you would not have an issue as the page should not be in the index at all. If it is, then something is going wrong with the publishing process.

If we are talking DXA - the idea behind the search module is to provide a simple 1-box search on all published pages/pdfs (except pages excluded by page meta). If you want to customize this I'm afraid you are going to need to do some coding of your own.

Comment: Not sure why our config default field element isn't being listened but adding to the querystring will suffice for now. On the suppress you are correct will - this is what I meant and it was in the publishing! And your last point is always a difficult one to drive home with the client but we've drilled it into them ... out of the box = out of the box +/- the odd tweak! Thanks for the response :)